# How to properly size content on ScrollView for all devices?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, scrollview, nib

I am using a scrollview along with Nibs. The goal is to layout 3 nibs with image inside them and scroll through them. I am also using storyboards to layout the scrollview.

The issue is venting looks good besides on the iPhone Plus sizes. The nibs are not centered right and bleeds on the screen? how do I fix this? Please check my code below.

```
@IBOutlet private weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        imageArray = [imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree]
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width * CGFloat(imageArray.count), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)

        loadOnboardingDescriptions()


    }

        // MARK: Load onboarding dscription features

    func loadOnboardingDescriptions() {
        for (index, image) in imageArray.enumerated() {
            if let onboardingDescriptionView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(Constants.NibName.onboardingDescriptionView.rawValue, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? OnboardingDescriptionView {
                onboardingDescriptionView.onboardingImageView.image = UIImage(named: image["image"]!)
                onboardingDescriptionView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width
                onboardingDescriptionView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * self.view.bounds.size.width
                print(onboardingDescriptionView.frame.origin.x)
                self.scrollView.addSubview(onboardingDescriptionView)
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Matt bellow, I should have called this function inside:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    loadOnboardingDescriptions()
}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is _too soon_ to do what you're doing. You are assuming that `self.view.bounds.width` has achieved its final value (the width of the screen). That's not true; that hasn't happened yet. Therefore all your values, which depend on that value, are coming out wrong.

Comment: where would you set this then? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, personally I wouldn't do what you're doing at all. I'd use a scrolling UIPageViewController. Or at least I'd lay the entire thing out with autolayout constraints.

Comment: But if you're really sold on doing it this way, you need to wait until after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` has fired for the first time. That is when your manual measurements will come out correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Well what Im trying to so is have scrollview or if possible I would use a UIPageViewController to be placed in a view controller so the user can just swipe that part. Its for an onboarding. I don't want the whole 'page to scroll though'

Comment: If you don't want paging (one subview at a time) then UIPageViewController would be wrong. I do not know what the word "onboarding" means. The nice thing about using constraints is that everything can work automatically in relation to whatever the width of the screen / scroll view turns out to be.

Comment: What you suggested fixed the problem! Thanks so much!

Comment: But be careful: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` can be called many times. You only want to add your subviews the _first_ time.